# About TetGenTetrahedralize Mesh Size

Tags: computational-geometry, tetgenlink

I have used TetGenTetrahedralize to generated a cubic mesh.

I want that the edge size of the triangle to be 0.2, how can realized this?

And What does the word "pq1.414a1" mean?
inst1 = TetGenTetrahedralize[ inst, "pq1.414a1"]

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"];
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];

long = 15;
broad = 15;
height = 15;

inst = TetGenCreate[];

pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {long, 0, 0}, {long, broad, 0}, {0, broad, 0}, {0, 
    0, height}, {long, 0, height}, {long, broad, height}, {0, broad, 
    height}};
facets = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{5, 6, 7, 8}}, {{1, 5, 6, 2}}, {{2, 6, 7, 
     3}}, {{3, 7, 8, 4}}, {{4, 8, 5, 1}}};

TetGenSetPoints[inst, pts];
TetGenSetFacets[inst, facets];

inst1 = TetGenTetrahedralize[ inst, "pq1.414a1"]
elemPts = TetGenGetPoints[inst1];
elemFaces = TetGenGetFaces[inst1];

Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[elemPts, Polygon[elemFaces]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to generate a mesh from a `Cuboid`. The meaning of the string is documented in V10 on the `TetGenTetrahedralize` ref page (also [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/TetGenLink/ref/TetGenTetrahedralize.html) in the details section.)

The string option `a1` tells TetGen to generate a mesh with has tetrahedra that are no larger than a volume of 1. (Unfortunatly there is a bug in TetGen 1.4.3 that does not always respect that request.) So to get an edge length you'd have to convert that into what that would mean as a volume for a tetrahedron. As a very rough estimate we use

```
Volume[Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.2}, {0, 0.2, 0}, {0.2, 0, 
    0}}]]
0.00133333
```

The with

```
TetGenSetPoints[inst, pts];
TetGenSetFacets[inst, facets];

inst1 = TetGenTetrahedralize[inst, "pq1.414a0.0013"]
elemPts = TetGenGetPoints[inst1];
elemFaces = TetGenGetFaces[inst1];

Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[elemPts, Polygon[elemFaces]]]
```

Here is a different way to get to that result:

```
R1 = DiscretizeGraphics[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {long, broad, height}]]
mr = TriangulateMesh[R1, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.2}];
```

The we use

```
MeshCellCount[mr, 3]
Mean[PropertyValue[{mr, 1}, MeshCellMeasure]]
4898432
0.201541
```

So we have about 5M tets and the edge length is about 0.2

Comment: @ user21,The question is how can I get the mesh points coordinates and the element connectivities ...

Comment: @YuYong, I think that's a followup question, perhaps it's better if you ask a new question.